# `cd` not working if used in bash script

Tags: bash, cd-command

I cannot use `cd` anymore when using it in a bash script

```
[~/Downloads] # cat cd-backward
#!/bin/bash
cd ..

[~/Downloads] # ./cd-backward
[~/Downloads] #
```

I should move to `~` at the last line.

`cd` works perfectly in terminal strangely. Nothing happens also when I run `bash -c 'cd Download` for instance.

Comment: it works. in the script it goes to ~. then exit back to where it was before i.e. ~/Downloads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every script is executed in its own `subshell`, that is a separate
process that cannot modify its *parent* working directory.  The only
way to change a working directory using a script written to a file is
sourcing it using `.` or `source` (they are equivalent) like this:

```
$ . cd-backward
```

or

```
$ source cd-backward
```

Note that in such case you don't even need `shebang` (`#!/bin/bash`) at the top of your script.

Comment: What is "to source the file"? I need to create one file, with short name `cdlb` that will be a shortcut to `cd /usr/local/bin`. How to achieve that?

Comment: `What is "to source the file"?` - `help source`.

Comment: `I need to create one file, with short name cdlb that will be a shortcut to cd /usr/local/bin. How to achieve that?` - create an alias: `alias cdlb="cd /usr/local/bin"`

Answer (score 2):

When you launch a script, it runs in [its own shell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html), as Arkadiusz already mentioned. In this case, you have instance of `bash`. You can see it if you modify the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
pwd
```

Sample run on my system gives :

```
bash-4.3$ pwd
/home/xieerqi/Downloads
bash-4.3$ ./cd-backward 
/home/xieerqi
bash-4.3$ pwd
/home/xieerqi/Downloads
```

Appropriately enough, within the script subshell, you navigate to home directory. Parent shell's current working directory however remains unchanged

Answer (score 2):

Your process (called `$$`) has a "Current directory", `~/Downloads`.

When you `./cd-backward`, that Bash script is run in its own process, which has its own "Current Directory", which starts off as `~/Downloads`.

The `cd ..` affects the "Current Directory" of the `./cd-backward` process, changing it to `~`, but NOT affecting the "Current Directory" of your original process.

`./cd-backward` finishes, its process exits, and the `cd ..` is forgotten about.

Here are two ways I affect my own "Current Directory", kept in my '~/.bashrc`:

First, a couple of `alias`es:

```
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd .. ; cd ..'
```

Here's how I keep my current directory in my Window title (through intercepting `cd`):

```
# from the "xttitle(1)" man page - put info in window title
update_title()
{
    [[ $TERM = xterm ]] || [[ $TERM = xterm-color ]]  && xttitle "[$$] ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:$PWD"
}

cd()
{
    [[ -z "$*" ]] && builtin cd $HOME
    [[ -n "$*" ]] && builtin cd "$*"
    update_title
}
```